# hide the default value of a textBoxFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Note - this is an asp.net MVC 4 application using Razor 2 views...
basically I have a textbox in a view waiting for the user to input data,
this data makes up the values for properties of a model which I want to save to the Db.

The data associated with this textbox has a [required] tab in the Model. I cannot save the model without a value for this textbox as the Model is not valid.

I know I can simply add @Value to the @HtmlTextBoxFor line, put this means that value is displayed to the user.

Is there away to have a default value hidden, so that the user only see's the placeholder text but the "value" will be saved to the Db. 
Any ideas...?

textbox..

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.Article.Title, new { @class = "span4 m-wrap", rows = 1 , @placeholder = "Enter your News Articles main subject or Title here" , @Value = "Title"})
```

controller

```
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    NewsArticle newNews = new NewsArticle();
    newNews.Title = newsArticle.Article.Title;
```

Comment: Even if you do this, the automatically-generated client-side validation code will fail on required unless you use JS to populate the empty field before submit (and before validation).

Comment: Codelgnoto - no, I mean the default value is not seen by the user but will be used so that the model isValid and proceeds to save to the Db.

Comment: lc, it works as above, saves to the database but the default value is displayed, or do you mean if "value" is hidden then it won't be saved to the Db.

Comment: Without being judgmental of your solution, I urge you to rethink it.  This field is required, yet the user can submit it as empty and the code will insert a default value that the user is not even aware of (as they can not see it on screen). Once again, you may have a good reason for this, in that case disregard above :) And in that case, just remove the required attribute and have the setter of the property on the model insert the default value if the attempted value is empty (assuming you have the option to do so)

Comment: Please judge away, I am still learning, so am open to any and all suggestions, I was trying to avoid removing the required tag, as I don't want to interfere with the Db right now and my other option is to introduce some validation, which I may do as well, but I'll have to  study up on more jquery...thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an ID to the textbox as follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.Article.Title, new { @class = "span4 m-wrap", rows = 1 , @placeholder = "Enter your News Articles main subject or Title here" , @Value = "", @id="txtTitle"})
```

Then call following jquery function on form submit event

```
$(function(){   
    $("form").submit(function () {
        if($("#txtTitle").val() == ""){
            $("#txtTitle").val("Default Value");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be picking up the jquery function, I have it between script tags after the last /div tag, am I missing something ?

Comment: You are missing jquery reference

Include it like `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`